# How to read bunch of message from Azure Service Bus - subscription using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus

I am new to python, I am trying to pull data from Azure Service Bus from subscription using python

I am running below code but throwing error

```
with subscription_client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver:
    messages = queue_receiver.fetch_next(timeout=3)
    for message in messages:
        print(message)
        message.complete()
```

Error:-

> azure.servicebus.common.errors.ServiceBusConnectionError: Failed to
>   open handler: Unable to open authentication session on connection

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to open up the  [specific ports](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c3e203a1-553c-4eae-8972-c2cb4bca6979/azure-event-hub-not-connecting?forum=servbus), could be **5671** and **5672**

Comment: In which side port should be open in my server side or azure server side ?

Comment: Service bus which is from azure side

Comment: @4c74356b41 i mean from the service which OP is using service bus https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide